# What do the hash signs in #if, #else, #end if mean?

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements

I'm writing code to check if a file is available to be checked out of SharePoint and, if it isn't, alert the user and tell them that the file is in use by someone else and who has it in use.

I came across a piece of code at http://www.xcelfiles.com/IsFileOpen.html#anchor_37

The code seems to work in test scenarios so I am planning to adapt it for my purposes. I'm having trouble understanding some of the syntax.

```
#If Not VBA6 Then

'// Xl97

For i = j - 1 To 1 Step -1

    If Mid(strXl, i, 1) = Chr(0) Then Exit For

Next

i = i + 1

#Else

'// Xl2000+

i = InStrRev(strXl, strFlag1, j) + Len(strFlag1)

#End If
```

I understand what the code does but I don't get the significance of the '#' symbol.

Another example:

```
hdlFile = FreeFile

Open strPath For Binary As #hdlFile

strXl = Space(LOF(hdlFile))

Get 1, , strXl

Close #hdlFile
```

It is a pain to google because it is so vague.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The hash symbols represent a **preprocessor command**, which are commands that are processed prior to compilation, essentially producing dynamic / conditional code. These types of commands are often used in languages such as C/C++ to manage cross-platform programming techniques. A common usage is to check for a particular environment or platform (ie. VBA, Windows, MacOSX, etc), and then implement platform-specific code.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor

Comment: These are also known as _directives_ and are used for conditional compilation. They are called preprocessor commands because they are interpreted by a _preprocessor_ before being processed by the compiler.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks very much for the info. This makes the code much more understandable.

Answer (score 4):

The hash indicates that it's a directive.
Used for literally including or excluding code from compilation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ah135z7.aspx

whoops that's for vb.net isn't it.  Same concept I think.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is correct that your first code example are compile directives.

It's worth pointing out in case someone else comes across this question that your second code example is a different thing.  In this case these are file numbers used to identify text streams.  You will see them used in the context of the commands below.  They are completely unrelated to compiler directives.

Open "c:\test.txt" For Input As #hdlFile
Input #hdlfile
Print #hdlfile
Write #hdlfile
Close #hdlfile