# Use of symbol # (hash) in VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

What is the meaning of the use of the `#` symbol in Excel VBA?

It is used like this:

```
 a = b /100#
```

I don't understand the significance of `#` after the `100`?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The type-declaration character for Double is the number sign (#). Also called *HASH*

Other type declaration characters are:

1. Integer %
2. Long &
3. Currency @
4. Single !
5. Double #
6. String $

> Don't understand the significance of # here.

It implies that when the expression is evaluated, the number in front of the
type declaration character is treated as a specific data type instead of as
a Variant.

See this example, which are basically the same.

```
Sub Sample1()
    Dim a#

    a = 1.2

    Debug.Print a
End Sub

Sub Sample2()
    Dim a As Double

    a = 1.2

    Debug.Print a
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Let me explain it a little more in detail.

Consider this two procedures

```
Sub Sample1()
    Dim a As Double, b As Integer

    b = 32767
    a = b * 100

    Debug.Print a
End Sub

Sub Sample2()
    Dim a As Double, b As Integer

    b = 32767
    a = b * 100#

    Debug.Print a
End Sub
```

**Question**: One of them will fail. Can you guess which one?

**Ans**: The 1st procedure `Sub Sample1()` will fail.

**Reason**:

In `Sample2`, when you do `b * 100#` the result of calculation will be of type `Double`. Since it is within the limits of Double, so the calculation succeeds and the result is assigned to variable `a`.

Now in `Sample1`,  when you do `b * 100` the result of calculation will be of type `Integer`, since both the operands are of type integer. But the result of calculation exceeds the limits of Integer storage. As a result it will error out.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: +1 Even since the old VB times, I've found these shortcuts very handy. :)

Comment: @PradeepKumar: Yeah these shortcuts are handy but I never liked them :) I have always been very "expressive" with my declarations, I guess :P

Comment: Very well explained. I've seen a lot of developers getting confused with this. They don't seem to be able to distinguish between the fact that the memory variable used for calculation is different from the the target variable of assignment, and their data-types can be different. :)

Comment: +1 I wouldn't have the strength to explain all that, I would have just said "don't do it" :-P

Comment: what? 3276700 is 0,15% of the max value of an int?

Comment: +1 fantastic explanation, would just like to add that the hash symbol can also be used as a preprocessor command in vba if used at the beginning of the line http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325486/if-else-end-if-what-do-the-hash-signs-mean-in-vba