# Excel VBA: 1.0 becomes 1#

Tags: excel, vba

For some reason when I type

```
Dim version
version = 1.0
```

in the vb editior in excel, the editor automatically changes it to

```
Dim version
version = 1#
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Just a suggestion but maybe you should use a `String` variable for version?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890892/use-of-symbol-hash-in-vba-macro/10891051#10891051

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`version = 1#` tells the compiler to assign a double.

The [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee199514.aspx) defines other suffixes:

- `1!` is a Single
- `1@` is a Currency
- `1` is also a double in the context of assigning to a double variable