# What is 1# in excel Macros?

Tags: excel

Does anyone know what `1#` means in excel macros? I keep seeing it in macros code but do not know what it means.

For example: `avg_change = 1#`.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 2):

The type-declaration character for Double is the number sign `#`. Also called `HASH`

Some of the other type declarations are:

```
Integer %
Long &
Currency @
Single !
Double #
String $
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a type declaration. The # (hash) is used to declare type Double.

See: [Use of symbol # (hash) in VBA Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890892/use-of-symbol-hash-in-vba-macro)