# FreeFile Hashtag

Tags: vba, excel

When assigning the freefile return in VBA for excel to an integer, why do all future calls referencing this integer require a hashtag symbol before the variable?

For example:

```
Dim fileName As String, textData As String, textRow As String, fileNo As Integer
fileName = "C:\test.txt"
fileNo = FreeFile 'Get first free file number  
textData ="Hello World!"
Open fileName For Output As #fileNo
Write #fileNo, textData
Close #fileNo
```

Why does the variable fileNo have to be reference as #fileNo? Is this another way of type declaration like I found here?

[Use of symbol # (hash) in VBA Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890892/use-of-symbol-hash-in-vba-macro)

Thanks!

Comment: The hashtag at the beginning indicates that the variable holds a file like handle. The hashtag at the end indicates that the variable holds a `Double` type.

Comment: Thank you! I see the difference now.

Comment: I think that's just a syntax hangover from the original BASIC interpreters of the 1960s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like many features which exist in VBA, such as `GoSub...Return`, `While...Wend` and optional line numbering, this syntax is a holdover from the various implementations of BASIC. [Here](http://www.qb64.net/wiki/index.php/WRITE_(file_statement)) is an example of it used in QBasic.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.

Comment: Note also that the filenumber should be long such as #fileno& since it may overflow integer.