# VBA reading XML performance issues

Tags: excel, xml, vba, xmldom

I have already looked here for many answers, but none of them seems to cover my problem. In fact, many of the suggestions given in other answers are already implemented in my code.
I have a huge xml file that I must loop through, and the speed is really low, about 1 second per line written (or per node). This speed is also kept when I get a small sample, like 82 lines (with about 15 columns each). This would mean 82 main nodes with 15 child nodes each.

My code is as follows:

```vb
Dim wsBase As Worksheet
Dim linEscrita As Long

Dim resp As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim lista As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim nodeAtual As IXMLDOMNode
Dim childNode As IXMLDOMNode

Dim charIni As Long
Dim charAt As Long
Dim colAtual As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wsBase = Worksheets("Name of worksheet")

Set resp = New DOMDocument60
resp.LoadXML (FunctionForGettingXMLfromWebService)

linEscrita = 2
'name from Node I must find and get child nodes
Set lista = resp.SelectNodes("//node1/node2")

For Each nodeAtual In lista
    colAtual = 1
    If (nodeAtual.HasChildNodes) Then
        For Each childNode In nodeAtual.ChildNodes
            wsBase.Cells(linEscrita, colAtual) = childNode.text
            colAtual = colAtual + 1
        Next childNode
    End If
    linEscrita = linEscrita + 1
Next nodeAtual

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

This code is even really similar to a code found here on an answer, and on that answer the code has results much faster than mine. This is not pc based problem, as I have tried in other computers as well. Has anyone gone through something similar or have any idea what might be the problem? The XML goes fine and fast when looped with PHP, so not a XML problem as well.

Comment: Please show us sample of input XML and desired output. It appears you are only summing values. Also, how *huge* is *huge* in *huge xml file*? Over 1GB?

Comment: Two immediate efficiencies: 1) replace `For Each childNode In nodeAtual.ChildNodes` with `for x = 1 to nodeAtual.ChildNodes.Count` as a for loop is much quicker than a for each loop. 2) Don't write to the sheet at every iteration (`wsBase.Cells(linEscrita, colAtual) = childNode.text`), instead create an array and populate that, then write the array to the sheet

Comment: Thank both of you for the tips. Parfait sorry I didn't put the XML, actually I wasn't even saying it, just storing it in the variable and cleaning it after so as to be faster. Absinthe, thank you for the tips, they really helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Array method**

Looping through a range via VBA is always time consuming. Therefore the following code example - *as close as possible to your original post* *) - writes the wanted XML contents into a predefined 2-dim **array** (section `[3]`and `[4]`) and writes it back to sheet via one single code line (section `[5]`).
Furthermore it's assumed in this very basic XPath model that all 15 subnodes follow the same strict order; empty lines will be omitted.

*) *You could speed this up by direct reference to the childnodes as proposed by @Absinthe.*

**Code example as close as possible to your OP**

```
Sub WriteXMLContents2Sheet()
  Const MAXCOLUMNS& = 15                          ' << change to columns limit in xml
  Dim linEscrita As Long: linEscrita = 2          ' << start row

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim wsBase     As Worksheet
  Set wsBase = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of worksheet")
'[1] load xml
  Dim resp       As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
  Dim lista      As IXMLDOMNodeList
  Dim nodeAtual  As IXMLDOMNode
  Dim childNode  As IXMLDOMNode
  Set resp = New DOMDocument60
  resp.LoadXML (FunctionForGettingXMLfromWebService)
'[2] set nodelist to memory (XPath possibly could be refined :-)
  Set lista = resp.SelectNodes("//node1/node2")
'[3] dimension temporary variant (1-based) 2-dim array to hold contents
  ReDim tmp(1 To lista.Length, 1 To MAXCOLUMNS)
' [4] loop thru nodelist
  Dim c&, r&                                            ' declare row/column counters
  r = 1
  For Each nodeAtual In lista
    c = 1
    If nodeAtual.HasChildNodes Then
        For Each childNode In nodeAtual.ChildNodes
            tmp(r, c) = childNode.Text
            c = c + 1                                   ' increment column counter
        Next childNode
        r = r + 1                                       ' << move row counter into If condition to avoid empty lines
    End If
  Next nodeAtual
'[5] write array content to sheet
  wsBase.Range("A" & linEscrita).Resize(UBound(tmp), UBound(tmp, 2)) = tmp

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer did it. Using the array really saved a lot of time and made the XML time closer to what is expected to be.

Comment: You are welcome; you could even avoid the `If` condition by setting the nodelist to nodes with sub elements as follows: `Set lista = resp.SelectNodes("//node1/node2[*]")` - @DanielFittipaldi

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I will try it. Just one last question: what does the "&" by the var name means? As in c&, r& ?

Comment: Appreciate your efforts to learn. These hashes are sort of abbreviated type declarations, c.f. [Use of Symbol hash in VBA macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890892/use-of-symbol-hash-in-vba-macro/10891051#10891051)