# Defining multiple (For-Next) loop issues in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to define multiple (For-Next) loop, but i received the following error.

[image: Overflow error]

The code is designed to calculate values in cells (C50:C60), then use this values, to calculate values of cells (D50:D60)

I tried to wrote it in a one code, but i received that error, i tried to wrote it on 2 separates codes, but i still having this error.

Could any one help,
Thanks in advance.

The Code is :-

```
Sub CalculateFs()
For x = 50 To 60
If Cells(x, 2) > 0 Then
    Cells(x, 3) = (Abs(Cells(x, 1)) / (Cells(22, 1) * WorksheetFunction.Pi * Cells(22, 3) ^ 2 * 0.25) / Cells(40, 2)) + (Cells(x, 2) / (Cells(22, 1) * WorksheetFunction.Pi * Cells(22, 3) ^ 2 * 0.25))
Else
    Cells(x, 3) = Abs(Cells(x, 1)) / (Cells(22, 1) * WorksheetFunction.Pi * Cells(22, 3) ^ 2 * 0.25) / Cells(40, 2)
End If
Next x
For S = 50 To 60
    Cells(S, 4) = WorksheetFunction.Min(((95000 / Cells(S, 3)) - (2.5 * Cells(17, 2))), (300 * 252 / Cells(S, 3)), (300), ((94600 / Cells(S, 3)) - (2.5 * Cells(17, 2))))
Next S
End Sub
```

Note:-
The first part of the code (X-Values) is good and has no errors message, but the errors appears always with the second part (S-Values)

Comment: Have you researched what the [Overflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/overflow-error-6) error might mean? =).

Comment: Did you press the "debug" button, verified which variable is giving an overflow and gone from there?

Comment: yes i did, i mentioned in my inquiry, that, the error related to the second part of the code (S-Values), this was by using debug button. any way, Sir/(mx5_craig) answer is totally helpful, i recommend this answer for you and me, thanks for your concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JvdV points out the error is likely due to the following statement

> "You attempt to use a number in a calculation, and that number is
>   coerced into an integer, but the result is larger than an integer"

replace this line:

```
Cells(S, 4) = WorksheetFunction.Min(((95000 / Cells(S, 3)) - (2.5 * Cells(17, 2))), (300 * 252 / Cells(S, 3)), (300), ((94600 / Cells(S, 3)) - (2.5 * Cells(17, 2))))
```

with this:

```
Cells(S, 4) = WorksheetFunction.Min(((95000 / Cells(S, 3)) - (2.5 * Cells(17, 2))), (300& * 252& / Cells(S, 3)), (300), ((94600 / Cells(S, 3)) - (2.5 * Cells(17, 2))))
```

Effectively casting these numbers to a long (rather than an integer, [Use of symbol # (hash) in VBA Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890892/use-of-symbol-hash-in-vba-macro]))

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was very helpful. Could you please explain to me the limits of integer,Long, and the double, in plain language, when i use the integer, long, and the double. Thanks again

Comment: Hi, glad I could help.  A VBA integer can only represent a maximum value of 32767.  300 x 256 exceeds that maximum (despite the fact that those numbers in isolation don't).  A long can represent a much bigger number.  VBA will default use int, unless you specifically tell it not too.