# VBA Filling a number up (ex. 1-> 00001)?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I have a code snippet which tells me in which row a specific value is

```
With Tabelle1
Set pzrow = .Cells.Find(What:=pznr, LookIn:=xlValues, searchorder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False) ' sucht die Nummer der Zeile raus
End With
```

The value can differ between 1 and 29000.
Just for cosmetic reasons I want to display the row in a Label caption:

```
pzrow1.Caption = "Eintrag Nr. " & pzrow.Row
```

and this should show "Eintrag Nr. 00001" for example, not "Eintrag Nr. 1"

Some Ideas?

Comment: you could try this: `Format(pzrow.row, "00000")`

Comment: @braX yeah. I got If Not pzrow Is Nothing Then
        Else`  after it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Format$()` to specify how many digits:

```
pzrow1.Caption = "Eintrag Nr. " & Format$(pzrow.Row, "00000")
```

Comment: I've seen lately the `Format$` what is the `$` for braX?

Comment: It's optional... It used to be required, but not anymore. I just use it out of old habit.

Comment: @Damian: You will find an explanation [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890892/use-of-symbol-hash-in-vba-macro)

Comment: @SiddharthRout - I knew it meant `String` but since there is no math being done with it, why would it matter "back in the day"? (per your link)

Comment: @braX: Yes I am sure you knew. The comment was for Damian :) If I am not wrong, these are nothing but just shortcuts. Not sure about the "required part" though

Comment: @SiddharthRout - I found this out of curiosity - Format$ is to be used specifically on a string variable. Format is to be used on any other usable data type. Both return strings. Format$ will always prove that little bit faster as it doesn't have to convert a different data type to a string.