# Excel VBA returns Value Used in the formula is of wrong data type

Tags: excel, vba, function

I want a create a user defined function in excel. That converts a value based on input unit. But I get an error if the final result is lower than 1.
Function

```
Function ConvertQtyToMeterPerSecs(qty As Double, unit As String) As Double
    Dim ck As Double

    'Converting all to m3/secs
    If (unit = "cm/hr") Then
        ck = qty * ((1 / 100) / (60 * 60))
    ElseIf (unit = "cm/day") Then
        ck = qty * ((1 / 100) / (24 * 60 * 60))
    ElseIf (unit = "cm/sec") Then
        ck = qty * (1 / 100)

    ConvertQtyToMeterPerSecs=ck
End Function
```

When I call the function in a cell in excel it works fine but it will throw an error if for example the result is 0.32444

Comment: Please post your real code. This one doesn't even compile since it is missing an `End If`. Also, instead of posting which result throws the error, post which input leads to the result that throws the error. That will be so much easier to reproduce.

Comment: Change `24 * 60 * 60` to `24# * 60# * 60#` It defines each number as a double. [Interesting Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890892/use-of-symbol-hash-in-vba-macro)

Comment: Thank you @Siddharth. Its interesting to note that.

Comment: Was that causing the error? If not then what values did you pass to `qty` and `unit` and what error are you getting?

Comment: Note that the [International System of Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) defines the unit of seconds as `s` not `sec`. According [Non-SI units mentioned in the SI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-SI_units_mentioned_in_the_SI) I would recommend to use `h` for hours and `d` for days instead of the non-standard abberviations.