# How to use Word 2013 parameter in VBA template and compile in Word 2010

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm writing code for a template that needs to work in many Word versions (2003 through 2013, minus 2008). I've accepted that it won't compile in all of those versions. I mostly write my code in Word 2010. Up until now I've always been able to get it to compile in 2010, but now I've hit a stumbling block.

I need to add a comment to a document with a specific user name that I define. I do this by holding the current username and userinitials in variables, setting them to what I want, adding my comment, and then resetting the parameters. Simple enough. However, in Word 2013 an additional parameter must be set in order to get this to work: Application.Options.UseLocalUserInfo. As this doesn't exist in Word 2010, I can't compile.

I recognize this is mostly just an inconvenience (I can comment out that code, check for compile issues, and then uncomment it). But I wanted to check and see if there was a better, less hinky solution. Most of my experience with cross-version compatibility is in using compiler constants and late binding, neither of which help here (as far as I can tell).

The basic code is below. Thanks!

```
    With Application
       sDocAuthorName = .UserName
       sDocAuthorInitials = .UserInitials
       If IsWord2013 = true Then bUseLocal = GetUseLocalUserInfo
   End With

   With Application
       .UserName = sQAAuthorName
       .UserInitials = sQAAuthorInitials
       If IsWord2013 = true Then .Options.UseLocalUserInfo = True
   End With

   'Do something

   With Application
       .UserName = sDocAuthorName
       .UserInitials = sDocAuthorInitials
       If IsWord2013 = true Then .Options.UseLocalUserInfo = bUseLocal
   End With
```

Comment: `Application.Options.UseLocalUserInfo`- where do you have it from? I can't see this on [THIS LIST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn353005.aspx)

Comment: Check [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325486/if-else-end-if-what-do-the-hash-signs-mean-in-vba) out. I have seen other people use *directive* commands like these in VBA to account for different versions.

Comment: @KazJaw that's odd. According to this thread (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/09382026-5b75-4793-96a4-b0b4a6a097d7/always-use-these-values-regardless-of-sign-in-to-office?forum=worddev) it's just not documented. Maybe a late addition? I don't have 2013 handy, but according to the link it is in the object browser.

Comment: @DavidZemens I would love to do that, but I don't believe MS provides compiler constants for Word versions. If word 2013 used a different version of VBA, I'd be set, but I don't think that's the case. I use them to differentiate Mac-only code; really wish they'd add versions.

Comment: FWIW There is more about this parameter here (AFAIK it's still not listed in the MSDN documentation) http://blogs.msmvps.com/wordmeister/missing-office-documentation/word-object-model/

Comment: @Christina OK. I have a suggestion I'll post it as an answer and let's see if that helps.

Comment: You can get away with the constants thing in this case because Word 2013 is the first version that uses VBA7. But you are right, it is a kludge to use the version of VBA for this kind of thing.

Comment: @bibadia Hmm, my Word 2010 VBA says that it is VBA7. I'll have to investigate, but yeah, I don't want to base this on faulty logic.

Comment: @Christina - yes, you're right, sorry. In that case the only way you can use conditional compiler arguments is to set your own and release different versions for Word 2013 and Word 2010, which I doubt anyone in the real world can really get away with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Word 2013 so I can't test in that environment, but I do have Word 2010, and this code compiles if you use late-binding:

```
Sub Foo()
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim IsWord2013 as Boolean
    IsWord2013 = False
    Set wdApp = Application

    If IsWord2013 Then wdApp.Options.UseLocalUserInfo = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, wow, i didn't even think of using late binding on the Application object itself. I will test but I'm almost sure this will work. Thanks! Will return and mark as answer once I've done my due diligence.