# Conditional mechanism in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, extensibility

I have a .dot file with one line of code that must be executed in a Microsoft Word macro if and only if the version of Word 2003 or greater is installed, otherwise it shuold be ignored.  I tried to implement it like this, hoping that Visual Basic for Word compiles a line only if it needs to execute it.  The code in question is the following (Word 2003 is 11.0)

```
If Val(Application.Version) >= 11 Then
    ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = False
End If
```

I still want that the .dot file with the macro is usable in earlier versions of Microsoft Word, such as Microsoft Word 2000.

However, if I try to run the .dot file, it fails on Word 2000 with a compile error because `ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout` is not a valid method in Word 2000.  That is, even when the line will never be executed on Word 2000 because `Application.Value` will be 9.0, Word still tries to compile that line.

Is there any way in Visual Basic for Word to add compiler directives so that some code is not compiled depending on the Word version?

Comment: do you know what conditional compilation is?

Comment: I checked the compiler constants than can be used with conditional compilation and none of them seems to be related with the version of Office.  There are constants for Visual Basic version, but not for Office version.

Comment: a really dirty approach would be to check the application version and then based on the result create a module programmatically and add the code? if you consider that approach i can give you a solution

Comment: @mehow I was considering creating a second .dot file that actually called the ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = False instruction.  Do you mean that with your solution, it is not necessary to create a separate .dot file that will only execute if Val(Application.Version) >= 11?

Comment: With *my approach* you wouldn't need to create another file. What would happen would use the Open event of the Doc file. Once it opens it checks the Word version. If the version is 2003 or UP then it executes a Sub that will automatically(programmatically) add a module(literally create a new module and put code in it) to the VBA project and execute a macro in that module.

Comment: This code is found in a .dot file Sub that is called from an external executable.  The line prior this the version check, actually opens the file so I guess the code of your approach could be added here.  The line preceeding the version check is: Documents.Open FileName:=aInpFileName, ConfirmConversions:=False, _
        ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", _
        PasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, WritePasswordDocument:="", _
        WritePasswordTemplate:="", Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto

Comment: I've given you an answer so try that and see if it does what you want it to do

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. The .dot file with the macro is included in shrink-wrapped software distributed to thousands of users, will they have to explicitly authorize the macros in their Microsoft Office setups?

Comment: See the suggestion by David Zemens at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569407/how-to-use-word-2013-parameter-in-vba-template-and-compile-in-word-2010#comment29046086_19569407

Comment: @bibadia Late binding seems an interesting option. I'll check if the following code: "If Val(Application.Version) >= 11 Then
    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    obj.ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = False
End If" does the trick.

Comment: Just for the record, we ended up implementing it with the late binding approach, as this avoided the compile time error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up implementing it with late binding, which turned out to be a very small tweak:

```
If Val(Application.Version) >= 11 Then
    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    obj.ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = False
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Their are two tricks to get it working:

1)
Add a module for functions that work only in specific office version and add your subroutines to it.

2)
In places where you have to call your functions, add a test for the specific Office Version and then call your subroutine with `Application.Run`

The original Module would have:

```
If Val(Application.Version) >= 11 Then
    Application.Run "office11module.disableReadingLayout"
End If
```

And your specific Module `office11module` would have

```
Public Sub disableReadingLayout()
    ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = False
End Sub
```

This works because Word is not compiling the office11module until it is needed, and we make sure through the `Application.Run` call that Word does not know that we need it before runtime.

Answer (score -1):

Our Word VBA Products require a Digital Signature.

We utilize MS Office 2000 as a base development application in order to be as backward compatible as possible with some of our clients.

We utilized the solution provided by jonas_jonas (Jan 16 '14 at 17:59) for years while using Word 2000 on Windows XP development platforms.

However - after upgrading to Windows 7 Pro development platforms, the solution no longer worked, giving us "Disk full" errors when attempting to save the Word files after having digitally signed them.

We then tried, and successfully used, the answer (above) provided by Pep (Jan 18 '14 at 23:23) which ***works when you need to Digitally Sign the Word file***.

We figured the "disk full" error was a result of the attempt to compile the project before saving.

```
If Val(Application.Version) >= 11 Then
    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    obj.ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = False
End If
```