# VBA "Compile Error: Statement invalid outside Type Block"

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am running a VBA Macro in Excel 2010 with tons of calculations, so data types are very important, to keep macro execution time as low as possible.

My optimization idea is to let the user pick what data type all numbers will be declared as (while pointing out the pros and cons of each data type, the balance between accuracy/flexibility and CPU intensiveness/macro execution time). However, when I run the macro, I get the following error message:

> Compile error:
>
> Statement invalid outside Type block

Here is the offending portion of the code:

```
Ind2 As Double, BgrValP As Double, BgrRow As Double, M40eff As Double
```

Here is the relevant part of the macro:

```
' Develop fake data to at glance recognize whether program works.
' Source http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optimize.htm
Option Explicit

Private Sub Function1()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim userChoice As Variant
Dim strPath As String, strFileN As String, strDirN As String, strRangeNOut As String, strRangeNIn As String, strFilename As String, strTLCorn As String, strBRCorn As String, strSelectedFile As String, strtemp_name As String
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim vResMatrix(), vCPath, vFileN As Variant

'   MEeff = measure of efflux due to crudely purified HDL in scintillation
'   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae55hdtk.aspx

'   Give the user macro options based on how fast or slow the computer is
userChoice = MsgBox("This macro by default treats all numbers as doubles for maximum precision. If you are running this macro on an old computer, you may want to redeclare numbers as singles, to speed up the macro." & vbNewLine & "You can also use integers for a quick estimate of data results.")

If userChoice = "Double" Then
    Dim RangeNOut As Double, vRangeNIn As Double, Ind6 As Double, Ind4 As Double, Ind5 As Double
    Dim Step2 As Double, MRow As Double, ColIn As Double, Ind3 As Double, Mcol As Double
    Dim MxRNo As Double, BgrSum As Double, RowIn As Double, Ind As Double, M40eff As Double, Step As Double
    Dim ColNo As Double, Startcol As Double, Startrow As Double, MeanComp As Double
    Dim PlateNo As Double, MonoVal As Double, Ind1 As Double, EntryRow2 As Double, EntryRow As Double
    Ind2 As Double, BgrValP As Double, BgrRow As Double, M40eff As Double
    Dim BrgSum As Double, BgrVal As Double, RangeNIn As Double, RangeNOut As Double, TLCorn As Double
    Dim Volcorr As Double, BRCorn As Double, MEeff As Double, MediaVal As Double

ElseIf userChoice = "Integer" Then
    Dim RangeNOut As Integer, vRangeNIn As Integer, ecInd6 As Integer, Ind4 As Integer, Ind5 As Integer
    Dim Step2 As Integer, MRow As Integer, ColIn As Integer, Ind3 As Integer, Mcol As Integer
    Dim MxRNo As Integer, BgrSum As Integer, RowIn As Integer, Ind As Integer, M40eff As Integer
    Dim Step As Integer, ColNo As Integer, Startcol As Integer, Startrow As Integer, MeanComp As Integer
    Dim PlateNo As Integer, MonoVal As Integer, Ind1 As Integer, EntryRow2 As Integer, EntryRow As Integer
    Dim Ind2 As Integer, BgrValP As Integer, BgrRow As Integer, M40eff As Integer
    Dim BrgSum As Integer, BgrVal As Integer, RangeNIn As Integer, RangeNOut As Integer, TLCorn As Integer
    Dim Volcorr As Integer, BRCorn As Integer, MEeff As Integer, MediaVal As Integer

ElseIf userChoice = "Single" Then
    Dim RangeNOut As Single, vRangeNIn As Single, ecInd6 As Single, Ind4 As Single, Ind5 As Single
    Step2 As Single, MRow As Single, ColIn As Single, Ind3 As Single, Mcol As Single
    Dim MxRNo As Single, BgrSum As Single, RowIn As Single, Ind As Single, M40eff As Single, Step As Single
    Dim ColNo As Single, Startcol As Single, Startrow As Single, MeanComp As Single
    Dim PlateNo As Single, MonoVal As Single, Ind1 As Single, EntryRow2 As Single, EntryRow As Single
    Ind2 As Single, BgrValP As Single, BgrRow As Single, M40eff As Single
    Dim BrgSum As Single, BgrVal As Single, RangeNIn As Single, RangeNOut As Single, TLCorn As Single
    Volcorr As Single, BRCorn As Single, MEeff As Single, MediaVal As Single

Else
    GoTo Function1
    MsgBox("This is not a supported data type: double, single, or integer.", vbCritical, "Unsupported Data Type")
```

Here is the code I am currently using for this:

```
Private Sub Function2(ByVal VarType As String)

Dim mVers As String
Dim userChoice As Variant

'   Give the user macro options based on how fast or slow the computer is using advanced conditional compliling
userChoice = MsgBox("This macro by default treats all numbers as doubles for maximum precision. If you are running this macro on an old computer, you may want to relare numbers as singles, to speed up the macro." & vbNewLine & "You can also use integers for a quick estimate of data results.")
userChoice = VarType

#If VarType = "Double" Or "double" Then
    Dim RangeNOut As Double, vRangeNIn As Double, Ind6 As Double, Ind4 As Double, Ind5 As Double
    Dim Step2 As Double, MRow As Double, ColIn As Double, Ind3 As Double, Mcol As Double
    Dim MxRNo As Double, BgrSum As Double, RowIn As Double, Ind As Double, M40eff As Double, Step As Double
    Dim ColNo As Double, Startcol As Double, Startrow As Double, MeanComp As Double
    Dim PlateNo As Double, MonoVal As Double, Ind1 As Double, EntryRow2 As Double, EntryRow As Double
    Dim Ind2 As Double, BgrValP As Double, BgrRow As Double, M40eff As Double
    Dim BrgSum As Double, BgrVal As Double, RangeNIn As Double, RangeNOut As Double, TLCorn As Double
    Dim Volcorr As Double, BRCorn As Double, MEeff As Double, MediaVal As Double
#ElseIf VarType = "Single" Or "single" Then
    Dim RangeNOut As Single, vRangeNIn As Single, ecInd6 As Single, Ind4 As Single, Ind5 As Single
    Step2 As Single, MRow As Single, ColIn As Single, Ind3 As Single, Mcol As Single
    Dim MxRNo As Single, BgrSum As Single, RowIn As Single, Ind As Single, M40eff As Single, Step As Single
    Dim ColNo As Single, Startcol As Single, Startrow As Single, MeanComp As Single
    Dim PlateNo As Single, MonoVal As Single, Ind1 As Single, EntryRow2 As Single, EntryRow As Single
    Dim Ind2 As Single, BgrValP As Single, BgrRow As Single, M40eff As Single
    Dim BrgSum As Single, BgrVal As Single, RangeNIn As Single, RangeNOut As Single, TLCorn As Single
    Dim Volcorr As Single, BRCorn As Single, MEeff As Single, MediaVal As Single
#ElseIf VarType = "Integer" Or "integer" Then
    Dim RangeNOut As Integer, vRangeNIn As Integer, ecInd6 As Integer, Ind4 As Integer, Ind5 As Integer
    Dim Step2 As Integer, MRow As Integer, ColIn As Integer, Ind3 As Integer, Mcol As Integer
    Dim MxRNo As Integer, BgrSum As Integer, RowIn As Integer, Ind As Integer, M40eff As Integer
    Dim Step As Integer, ColNo As Integer, Startcol As Integer, Startrow As Integer, MeanComp As Integer
    Dim PlateNo As Integer, MonoVal As Integer, Ind1 As Integer, EntryRow2 As Integer, EntryRow As Integer
    Dim Ind2 As Integer, BgrValP As Integer, BgrRow As Integer, M40eff As Integer
    Dim BrgSum As Integer, BgrVal As Integer, RangeNIn As Integer, RangeNOut As Integer, TLCorn As Integer
    Dim Volcorr As Integer, BRCorn As Integer, MEeff As Integer, MediaVal As Integer
#Else
    MsgBox "VarType " & VarType & " is not valid. Check spelling."
#End If

'   MEeff = measure of efflux due to crudely purified HDL in scintillation
MsgBox "For additional information about this macro:" & vbNewLine & "1. Go to tab Developer" & vbNewLine & "2. Select Visual Basic or Macro." & vbNewLine & "See the comments or MsgBoxes (message boxes)."

'   Start File Explorer to select file containing data (simple GUI, much easier than coding in the file)

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Show

'   Display paths of each file selected
    For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
    Next lngCount
    For Each strFilename In .SelectedItems
        MsgBox strFilename
        Function2
    Next
End With

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Error detected" & vbNewLine & "Error" & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error Handler: Error " & Err.Number
MsgBox "If you want to force the program to run, go to the line below and insert a ' mark to comment the line out." & vbNewLine & "On Error GoTo ErrorHandler", vbCritical, "Error Handler: Error " & Err.Number

End Sub
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have:

```
Dim RangeNOut as Double
Dim RangeNOut as Integer
```

While the `IF` statements in there are a nice idea, VBA will not allow you to do that. It doesn't do conditional 'compilation' since it isn't a compiled language. When VBA runs your code, all your variables are declared (no matter where in the code the `Dim` statement is located), then the code begins executing.

It's a nice idea you've come up with, but attempting this in VBA is like bringing a piece of Silly Putty™ to a gun fight - it's just horribly unequipped for the job.

Also, if you're *that* concerned about execution speed, VBA isn't your weapon of choice, either. I don't have any stats to back it up off the top of my head, but I doubt you'd actually see much difference in execution speed based on your three different variable types.

To pass the variable type as a parameter to the function, use this:

```
Private Sub Function1(ByVal VarType as String)

  #If VarType = "Double" then
    ...
  #ELSEIF VarType = "Single" then
    ...
  #ELSEIF VarType = "Integer" then
    ...
  #ELSE
    MsgBox "You passed in a 'VarType' of " & VarType & " - that's not valid"
  #ENDIF
```

Also, I just noticed that in your final `Else` you have `Goto Function1`. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish there, but:

1. Don't use `goto`. Except in VBA style error handling, it's *almost never* necessary
2. You don't have a label defined for the `Goto` to jump to, anyway.

See also [VBA function overloading](https://hammondmason.wordpress.com/2015/06/23/object-oriented-vba-overloading/) for another possible option.

**Notice:** Despite the upvotes and accepted answer status, I tried the following, and it **DOES NOT** work as requested by OP:

```
Sub test()
  func "Double"
  func "Single"
  func "Integer"
  func "String"
End Sub

Function func(v As String)
  #If v = "Double" Then
    Dim myvar As Double
    Range("A1") = "MyVar type is: " & vartype(v)
  #ElseIf v = "Single" Then
    Dim myvar As Single
    Range("a2") = "MyVar type is: " & vartype(v)
  #ElseIf v = "Integer" Then
    Dim myvar As Integer
    Range("a3") = "MyVar type is: " & vartype(v)
  #Else
    Range("A4") = "Invalid var type passed: " & v
  #End If

  MsgBox "Passed in " & v

End Function
```

All calls to `Func()` end up in the `#Else` section of code, populating `Range("A4")` with the `Invalid var type passed:` text.

Sadly, this will not work.

If it is truly necessary to have functions with different variable types doing the exact same thing, I think the following would be the best bet:

```
Sub Test()
  Dim VType as String

  While Vtype <> "Integer" and VType <> "Double" and VType <> "Single" and VType <> "Cancel"
    vType = msgBox("Enter variable type")
  Wend

  If VType = "Integer" then
    MyFuncInt()
  ElseIf VType = "Double" then
    MyFuncDouble()
  Elseif VType = "Single"
    MyFuncSingle()
  Else
    MsgBox "Function call cancelled"
  End if
End Sub

Function MyFuncInt()
  Dim AllTheVars as Integer
  ...
End Function

Function MyFuncDouble()
  Dim AllTheVars as Double
  ...
End Function

Function MyFuncSingle()
  Dim AllTheVars as Single
  ...
End Function
```

Comment: But... `#If [bool] Then`

Comment: Actually, VBA is compiled (sort of) and *does* support [conditional compilation](https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2014/11/21/setting-up-a-debug-environment-for-vba/). It's just incredibly difficult to change at runtime based on user input.

Comment: Agreed. Tens of thousands of calculations would probably only delay you by a two or three seconds if everything is a double. The best way to test it would be to write it in three different subs, test it out for each type, and time how long it takes to compile. I'd be curious to know the results, as well.

Comment: Well, [who knew](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325486/if-else-end-if-what-do-the-hash-signs-mean-in-vba) that VBA supports compiler directives!?!?! Can it be done the way the OP wants to handle it?

Comment: I see them being used to check for whether the code is running on a Mac: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990025/how-can-i-determine-if-my-vb-code-is-running-on-office-2016-for-mac.  I agree that the effect of this should be very small as long as they are not `Variant` which might make a difference.  The larger problem is that changing the declaration in this way can have a meaningful impact on downstream operations: equality tests with `Integer` are reasonable but not with a floating point type.

Comment: What's the easiest way to do this? I've read on the Microsoft Developer website that conditional compiling is easy, but often uses predefined constants:

Comment: Could I do this using self-defined constants?

Comment: See [@RubberDuck](https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2014/11/21/setting-up-a-debug-environment-for-vba/)'s writeup for more details, but yes, you have to use constants for it, you cannot do it with user entered variables within the `Sub()`/`Function()`. You _might_ be able to pass in a parameter that you could use in your `#IF`, but I'm not sure - it might be worth a try. However, before going down that rabbit hole (except as an academic exercise), I'd suggest that you run your function with each var type and _time_ it to see if it really makes that much difference.

Comment: @FreeMan how would I try to pass this in a parameter? Not realy sure what you mean. Also, there are debugging things and error handling to add, so I can't test the time differences yet, but this is still worth trying to conditionally compile, from a "prove my skill" thing.

Comment: @ThomasShera, I've updated to show passing the parameter in. For further learning, try [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+vba+parameter&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), there are a number of good examples there on how to pass in a parameter to a `Sub()` or `Function()` (they work exactly the same way).

Comment: I see you accepted the answer. Does that mean that passing the variable type as a parameter has worked for conditional compilation, or simply that you understand how to pass the parameter in? I was going to edit again to indicate that I wasn't sure if that would for for conditional compilation.

Comment: It seems to work (my program still has other errors). Is this a correct implementation: see the original question post above.

Comment: @RubberDuck, yeah, **no** it does _not_ work. Not sure what OP found that works for him, but I've documented the failure of this method in my post. I stand by my original 3 paragraphs.