# How can I determine if my VB code is running on Office 2016 for Mac?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, ms-word, powerpoint

Is there a conditional that I can use to differentiate if my Macro is running on Office 2016 for Mac or Office for Mac 2011

Answer (score 4):

In Office 2016 for Mac, there is a new conditional called MAC_OFFICE_VERSION to test which VB version the user is running.
The following example shows how it to use it in your code:

```
Sub VersionConditionals()
#If MAC_OFFICE_VERSION >= 15 Then
    Debug.Print "We are running on Mac 15+"
#Else
    Debug.Print "We are not running on Mac 15+"
#End If
#If Mac Then
    Debug.Print "We are running on a Mac"
#Else
    Debug.Print "We are not running on a Mac"
#End If
End Sub
```

Note: The "#If Mac" conditional remains unchanged from Office for Mac 2011.